# Не показывать пустую страницу до загрузки всех изображений

Tags: javascript, html, html5, reactjs

У меня есть галерея изображений, в которой все изображения рендерятся очень грубо говоря вот по такому шаблону

```
import image1 from './images/image1';
    <...>    
    render(){
        return(
        
             <img src={image1} alt="" />
        );
    }
```

То есть изображения грузятся не с сервера, а просто из папки, через импорт. И проблема в том, что когда я перехожу в эту галерею, сначала вижу просто лейаут без этих картинок, потом они прогружаются секунды две и тогда все нормально. Мне нужно, чтобы пока они грузятся, страница не показывалась, а было видно какой-нибудь спиннер.
Видел примеры, где его ставят, пока происходит фетч, но у меня его нет. Возможно ли такое?
Или хотя бы как-то анимацию сделать, чтобы изображения появлялись постепенно с изменением прозрачности?

Как вообще это реализуется?

[image: То, что вижу, когда страница еще загружается]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в общих чертах - вы можете воспользоваться `onLoad` & `onError` слушателями событий на теге `<img />` для обработки окончания загрузки. Ниже вы можете увидеть примерный код для компонента, который работает таким образом

```
import React from "react";

class ImageWithStatusText extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { imageStatus: "loading" };
  }

  handleImageLoaded() {
    this.setState({ imageStatus: "loaded" });
  }

  handleImageErrored() {
    this.setState({ imageStatus: "failed to load" });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <img
          src={this.props.imageUrl}
          onLoad={this.handleImageLoaded.bind(this)}
          onError={this.handleImageErrored.bind(this)}
        />
        {this.state.imageStatus}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default ImageWithStatusText;
```

Comment: Пример кода взят с https://www.javascriptstuff.com/detect-image-load/

Comment: Смысл в том, чтобы после того, как изображение загрузится, поменялось состояние и компонент перерендерился? Или как?

Comment: @TimofeyMelentev Да, именно. В `onLoad` и `onError` мы отслеживаем то, загрузилось ли окончательно изображение (или, произошла ли ошибка при загрузке). И потом на основании `this.state.imageStatus` мы можем рендерить UI по разному

Comment: А может ли помочь с ускорением загрузки хранение картинок в БД или где-нибудь еще? Если да, то как лучше хранить все-таки?

Comment: @TimofeyMelentev Думаю, оптимизация скорости загрузки изображений - это уже отдельный вопрос, он явно не в рамках этого вопроса. Задайте новый вопрос, и если с текущей проблемой я помог вам справиться - прошу принять мой ответ как верный. П.С. Можете отправить мне ссылку на ваш новый вопрос, я постараюсь вам с ним помочь